# AJAX update efficiency

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button of which can be held down to adjust a number, and that number will be updating a value in a database.

I am concerned that if i place the `AJAX` update where it is in the basic form it will attempt to update many times as per the increment and that would be terribly inefficient.

`What is an efficient way to only run the ajax update to the database once the user has not updated the number for x seconds?`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/2uJ9J/)

**The JS/JQ**

```
$('#btn').mousehold( function() {
    num = $('#1').text();
    num = parseFloat(num);
    num = num += 1;

    $('#1').text(num); 

    function updateDatabase() {
         //AJAX update here   
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would do a lot of request.

I suggest you tu use a setTimeout. Each time you clear the `timer`. And, if it gets 1 seconds without clearing, it run the AJAX request.

```
var timer;
$('#btn').mousehold( function() {
    var num = $('#1').text();
    num = parseFloat(num) + 1;

    $('#1').text(num); 

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        //AJAX REQUEST HERE
    },1000);

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `num` be declared as a local variable?  and `num = num += 1` should just be `++num`.

Comment: ah yes, i have a tendency to use php methods as i am primarily a php coder, relatively new to Javascript. Thanks though as that has cleared up a question i have wondered to myself for some time now! @jfriend00

Comment: He is setting into the ``#1`` element. It's not performatic. But works.